# Possible to use conditionals within add_feed() callback?

Tags: conditional-tags, feed

I'm using `add_feed()` to create some custom feeds but calls to `is_singular()`, `is_home()` etc... just don't seem to work within the callback. Is there a workaround for this?

Example code:

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_init' );
function my_init() {    
    add_feed( 'new_feed', 'feed_output' );
}

function feed_output() {
    if ( is_home() )
        load_template( '/path/to/feed/home/template.php' );
    else
        load_template( '/path/to/feed/template.php' );
}
```

I've added a [trac ticket](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/22031) for this too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) after the `posts_selection` [action hook](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request) has run.

According to the codex article on [add_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_feed) it should be called with the `init` action, which runs before. Now I don't know when and how you run it, because you don't say so in the above example, but I'd assume you do it before `posts_selection` - that would explain your dilemma anyway.

Comment: Thanks, I've added the context - I am actually calling it on init as the codex suggests. wp_head would be way too late as the output from the theme would already be rendering. Didn't seem to work on the wp action either...

Comment: Well tough luck, I guess.
Then, as far as I see it, it just is impossible to use add/remove feeds based on conditional tags.
Since `wp_head` is too late and `wp` doesn't cut it either, I removed my suggested yet untested way of handling things. The rest of the answer should still apply, I suppose.

Comment: Yeah, had a reply on the trac ticket. Apparently it doesn't make sense to return true for is_home etc... on a feed even though the feed changes with context...